# How to remove angular-fontawesome from a project?

Tags: angular, npm, font-awesome, npm-package, angular-fontawesome

I installed Angular fontawesome with this command found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome

```
ng add @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@6
```

My problem is I realized I wanted to change into Font Awesome's SCSS version and now I'd like to remove Angular Fontawesome (and the icons) from my project.

So far, I've tried these following commands

`npm uninstall @fortawesome/fontawesome`

`npm uninstall @fortawesome/fontawesome6`

`npm uninstall @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome`

Yet some of the dependencies still remain in my *package-lock.json*:

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do it is to delete the node_modules folder, remove what I don't want to have in the package.json and delete the package-lock.json.

Then I run npm install again and it generates a new package-lock.json and the node_modules folder will contain everything remaining in the package.json.

Comment: I thought about doing this, but never dared to try 'cause I was afraid I might lose something else in the process. Now that you mentioned this, I suppose I'll try this next time I run into problems like this! Thank you!

Comment: It can be quicker if you want to remove a lot of things, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Run also

```
npm uninstall @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm uninstall @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
npm uninstall @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
npm uninstall @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep going...

```
$ npm uninstall @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
$ npm uninstall @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
$ npm uninstall fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
$ npm uninstall @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```